# Create an array of object from ul li using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, html-lists

Im trying to create an array of `object` from `ul li` tags using `jQuery`. Unfortunately I'm not able to do that. I'm pasting my  code bellow.

```
var photos = [];
$( "#sliderContent li" ).each(function() {

  var title = $(this).find(".title").html();
  var image = $(this).find(".image".html());
  var url = $(this).find(".url").html();
  var firstline = $(this).find(".firstline").html();
  var secondline = $(this).find(".secondline").html();

  var slide = new Object();
  slide.title = title;
  slide.image = image;
  slide.url = url;
  slide.firstline = firstline;
  slide.secondline = secondline;
  photos.push(slide);
});
```

My HTML list `ul li`

```
<ul id="sliderContent" >
    <li>
        <div class="title">Stairs 1</div>
        <div class="image">vacation.jpg 1</div>
        <div class="url"># 1</div>
        <div class="firstline">Amazing Apartment for Rent in JBR 1</div>
        <div class="secondline">
            <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col1'>ABD 1</div>
                    <div class='col2'>EFG 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col1'>ABD 1</div>
                <div class='col2'>EFG 1</div>
           </div><div class='row'>
            <a class='view' href='#'></a>
            <a class='arrange' href='#'></a>
           </div>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is what i want to create.

```
var photos = [ {
    "title" : "Stairs",
    "image" : "vacation.jpg",
    "url" : "",
    "firstline" : "Amazing Apartment for Rent in JBR",
    "secondline" : "lorem ipsum"
}, {
    "title" : "Office Appartments",
    "image" : "work.jpg",
    "url" : "",
    "firstline" : "Amazing Apartment for Rent in JBR",
    "secondline" : "work?"
}];
```

Please tell me where did go wrong, and also how to view the content of the array `photos` to check the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe just a typo... but in this line `var image = $(this).find(".image".html());` you got the parantheses wrong.

Comment: Yea. that helped me to get through it. thanks buddy, you made my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while we're at it, in response to gurvinder372's answer, you could also create the object like this:

```
var slide = {
    title: title,
    image: image,
    url: url,
    firstline: firstline,
    secondline: secondline
};
```

instead of you original version:

```
  var slide = new Object();
  slide.title = title;
  slide.image = image;
  slide.url = url;
  slide.firstline = firstline;
  slide.secondline = secondline;
```

**EDIT**:
now, that i took some more time... You could in this case use the jQuery.map function like this:

```
var photos = $('#sliderContent li').map(function(index, liItem) {
    var $liItem = $(liItem);

    return {
        title: $liItem.find('.title').html(),
        image: $liItem.find('.image').html(),
        url: $liItem.find('.url').html(),
        firstline: $liItem.find('.firstline').html(),
        secondline: $liItem.find('.secondline').html()
    };
});
```

Remember to call this code only when the dom is ready (thus the list `sliderContent` exists). if you dont know the jQuery.map function, check out its doc: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Cool, never knew jQuery had a map function that worked like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `alert( JSON.stringify( photos ) );` to see the resulted object

you need to change

```
var slide = new Object();
```

to

```
var slide = {};
```

also, i am not able to make out how are you deducing 'secondline' from that html